# How do I set up HP LaserJet 4050 T and a Belkin Wireless N+ Router?

Tags: windows, macos, printer, network-printer

I have a HP LaserJet 4050 T and a Belkin Wireless N+ Router. I'd like to make my printer available on the network. I've looked at both HP's and Belkin's website, and I've not found the information I need.

I've got a few Windows (XP, Vista and 7) computers and a Mac and iPad. I'd like to ideally get an IP address assigned to the printer so I can take things from there.

What setting must I enable in the router? the printer?

Comment: Would this question do better on ServerFault?

Comment: @Moshe: No, this is a simple question about sharing a printer in a home-network, which fits IMO better on SU then SF. Also, does the printer have a built-in printserver?

Comment: @Bobby: No "N" in the HP printer model means no built-in print server.

Comment: @Ignacio - There is no N in the model number.

Comment: Yes, I saw it.​

Comment: Which model number?

Comment: Never mind, this is just confusing you.

Comment: Oks, so where can I get a cheap print server?

Comment: From the Interweb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a [print server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_server), either an external one or an EIO print server such as the [JetDirect 620n](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/18972-18972-236253-34213-236264-378355.html).